How do I add an apartment number to an address in Contacts?
How do I add an apartment or suite number to a contact’s address in the Contacts app? I am using an iPhone 15 running iOS 18. The only available address fields are street, city, state, zip, and country.


if you tap "add address" can you then do what you need to?

Just add it in one of the two street lines. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2810285?sortBy=rank

The contacts app provides you freeform "Street" fields to capture everything except the city, state, and ZIP Code. However, for US addresses, those things generally belong on one line so the second line is left blank.
If you prefer to split them, you can write information such as apartment, unit, or suite in the second "Street" line. However doing so is against recommendations from the postal service and would be strictly out of personal preference.


The delivery address is the most important information on your mailpiece. Use the following format for your delivery addresses:
Name or attention line:  JANE L MILLER
Company:                 MILLER ASSOCIATES
Delivery address:        1960 W CHELSEA AVE STE 2006R
City, state, ZIP Code:   ALLENTOWN PA 18104

If you can't fit the suite or apartment number on the same line as the delivery address, put it on the line ABOVE the delivery address, NOT on the line below.

Source: USPS
